# ActiveRecord timezone without rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord in a non-rails project. In rails I can do:

```
 config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

But if I am not using rails, how can I set the timezone?

Comment: [Is this of any help?](http://www.gittr.com/index.php/archive/activerecord-timezones-without-rails/)

Comment: @AlthafHameez link is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :local
```

also works for me.